# Python: File Handler Issue: Delete file without leaving .nsf files

Tags: python, logging, nsfilehandle

I have following method to handle logging in my python program

```
def createLogger(logger, logLang):
    """
    Setting up logger
    """
    log_format = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(filename=(os.path.join(OUT_DIR_LOGS, logLang + '-userdynamics.log')))
    file_handler.setFormatter(log_format)
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)
```

This is a large data collection code base and to avoid quota constrain on remote server, I have implemented following gzip and tar procedure,

```
def gzipLogs(lang):
    """
    Compressing and tar
    """
    # Compressing logfiles and removing the old logfile
    original_filePath = OUT_DIR_LOGS + "/" +lang + "-userdynamics.log"
    gzip_filePath = OUT_DIR_LOGS + "/" + lang +"-userdynamics.gz"
    with open(original_filePath , 'rb') as original_file:
        with gzip.open(gzip_filePath, 'wb') as zipped_file:
            zipped_file.writelines(original_file)
    os.remove(original_filePath)
    # Compressing language folders that has data
    folder_path = OUT_DIR + "/" + lang
    tar_file = tarfile.open(folder_path + ".tgz", "w:gz")
    # add timestamp to arch file
    tar_file.add(folder_path, arcname = NOW + "_" + lang)
    tar_file.close()
    # delete the original file
    shutil.rmtree(folder_path)
```

I do my data gather process in a nested for loop and I call the logger as mentioned bellow:

```
for something in somethings:
    for item in items:
        log = logging.getLogger()
        # Calling the logging configuration function.
        createLogger(log, lang)
```

Everything works fine but when it get executed, after deleting the file .nsf file residuals get left behind while causing the quota problem to remain as it is.

So I added following code segment to close the logging file handler but with this now I endup getting following error:

Code to close the log file:

```
unclosed_logs = list(log.handlers)
for uFile in unclosed_logs:
    print uFile
    log.removeHandler(uFile)
    uFile.flush()
    uFile.close()
```

Above code end up giving me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/somefilepath/SomePythonFile.py", line 529, in <module>
    main()
  File "/somefilepath/SomePythonFile.py", line 521, in main
    gzipLogs(lang)
  File "/somefilepath/SomePythonFile.py", line 61, in gzipLogs
    with gzip.open(gzip_filePath, 'wb') as zipped_file:
AttributeError: GzipFile instance has no attribute '__exit__'
```

This is how main method looks like with the handler closing code segment:

```
for something in somethings:
    for item in items:
        log = logging.getLogger()
        # Calling the logging configuration function.
        createLogger(log, lang)
    unclosed_logs = list(log.handlers)
    for uFile in unclosed_logs:
        print uFile
        log.removeHandler(uFile)
        uFile.flush()
        uFile.close()
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I handling the logger wrong? or am I closing the file too soon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I realize that server that I was executing the file was running against python 2.6 and in 2.6 GZip module didn't have `with open`. To answer for this question is either switch to python 2.7 or change the implementation to old fashion file open file in a try catch block.

```
try:
    inOriginalFile = open(original_filePath, 'rb')
    outGZipFile = gzip.open(gzip_filePath, 'wb')
    try:
        outGZipFile.writelines(inOriginalFile)
    finally:
        outGZipFile.close()
        inOriginalFile.close()
except IOError as e:
    logging.error("Unable to open gzip files, GZIP FAILURE")
```

This is how I fixed this problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things which could cause problems:

1. You should only configure logging (e.g. set levels, add handlers) in one place in your program, ideally from the `if __name__ == '__main__'` clause. You seem not to be doing this. Note that you can use `WatchedFileHandler` and use an external rotator to rotate your log files - e.g. [logrotate](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) provides rotation and compression functionality.
2. Your error relating to `__exit__` is nothing to do with logging - it's probably related to a Python version problem. `GZipFile` only became usable with `with` in Python 2.7 / 3.2 - in older versions, you will get the error message if you try to use a `GZipFile` in a `with` statement.